# Numpy WHERE IN equivalent

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm trying to select a subset from a numpy ndarray for my collaborative filtering project.

My array has this shape:

```
ratings = np.array(
    [
        (1, 2, 3.0),
        (2, 2, 3.0),
        (4, 1, 2.0),
        (1, 2, 1.0),
    ],
    dtype=[
        ('user_id', np.uint32),
        ('item_id', np.uint32),
        ('score', np.float32)
    ]
)
```

Now, I want to select a subset of ratings where user_id belongs to an array. Similar to SQL's 'WHERE IN' functionality.

I was able to achieve this using np.in1d:

```
subset_of_users = [1, 2]
ratings[np.in1d(ratings['user_id'], subset_of_users)]
```

My profiling always show that the blocks using in1d are the slowest, and it got me thinking that maybe there's a faster alternative of doing this.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author).

Inspired by your question, I have changed the API a bit, in a way such that we can benefit from repeated queries:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.contains(subset_of_users, ratings['user_id'])
```

Which should be read from left to right; 'subset contains elements of user_id', and returns the indices of 'user_id' present in the subset.

However, the most expensive part of the computation is building the 'index' for the set of user id's and this can be precomputed:

```
index = npi.as_index(ratings['user_id'])
npi.contains(subset_of_users, index)
npi.contains(some_other_subset_of_users, index)
```

Which I expect to be quite a bit faster, on a per-query basis.

Ive also integrated an npi.in_ function, inspired by Divakar's answer, which allows you to write npi.in_(ratings['user_id'], subset_of_users), which again reads left to right; the elements of user_id which are present in the subset'. But I expect it to be somewhat less efficient than using contains. That's all conjecture though; would be nice to see some comparisons on actual data!

Answer (score 0):

If your maximum user_id is not too large, you can use a lookup table:

```
mask_of_users = np.zeros(shape=max(ratings['user_id'])+1, dtype=bool)
mask_of_users[subset_of_users] = True
selected_ratings = ratings[mask_of_users[ratings['user_id']]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. max(user_id) is ~150k. Using this code my function went from 0.04s to 0.17s :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems the bottleneck there is `np.in1d`, so let's try to speed up that part. Now, from my NumPy experience so far, I came across one alternative with [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) that could be used as replacement for [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) for the case when the second array is a sorted and unique array or list and is to be matched against the elements in the first array. Listed below is the implementation -

```
def in1d_replacement(A,B):
    """ in1d replacement using searchsorted with optional 'left', 'right' args.
    """
    # Get left and right sorted indices for A in B
    idx_l = np.searchsorted(B,A,'left')
    idx_r = np.searchsorted(B,A,'right')

    # Look for switching indices between the left and right ones 
    # indicating the matches
    return idx_l != idx_r
```

Runtime test -

```
In [195]: # Random arrays of decent sizes
     ...: nA = 10000
     ...: nB = 1000
     ...: max_num = 100000
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0,max_num,(nA))
     ...: B = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,max_num,(nB)))
     ...: 

In [196]: np.allclose(np.in1d(A,B),in1d_replacement(A,B))
Out[196]: True

In [197]: %timeit np.in1d(A,B)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.73 ms per loop

In [198]: %timeit in1d_replacement(A,B)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.14 ms per loop
```

So, there is some performance boost if not a huge one.